# Bit parameter with Null value in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm having a bit value in my table, which contains bit (0 or 1) and NULL (as default).

Here is my SProc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE msp_CustomerStatistics 
   @Postal_MinValue int,
   @Postal_MaxValue int,
   @SubscriberState bit,
   @CustomerType varchar(50)
BEGIN
   [...]
   WHERE Sub = @SubscriberState
   AND Postal BETWEEN @Postal_MinValue AND @Postal_MaxValue
   AND CustType = @CustomerType
END
```

When I pass the @SubscriberState parameter with 1 or 0, the result is correct.
But when I pass null, the result is 0, which ain't correct.

If I create a SQL select with following where clause:

```
WHERE Sub IS NULL
```

Then the result shows the correct count.

Any idea how I make my Stored Procedure working with NULL parameter in my WHERE clause too??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use the `=` operator with null values. Comparisons with NULL always return false. Try to modify your WHERE statement to the following:

```
WHERE (Sub = @SubscriberState OR (@SubscriberState IS NULL AND Sub IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either set null values to 0 and check it like this:

```
WHERE Isnull(Sub,0) = @SubscriberState
```

or have a tri-state sort of bodge like:

```
WHERE Isnull(Sub,3) = isnull(@SubscriberState,3)
```

Comment: The question is: is a value of NULL to be treated the same as a value of 0, the same as a value of 1, or as a third value? The value NULL is not equivalent to either 0 or 1.

Comment: As Philip Kelley say, the Null value is treated the same way as 0 or 1 (yes I know the setup is some kind stupid, and should be redesigned, but thats the data I have right now :) ).
To sum it shortly, I want a count for each value seperately:
- How many 0
- How many 1
- How many NULL